# List all methods of a given class, excluding parent class's methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, methods

I'm building a unit testing framework for PHP and I was curious if there is a way to get a list of an objects methods which *excludes* the parent class's methods.  So given this:

```
class Foo
{

    public function doSomethingFooey()
    {
        echo 'HELLO THERE!';
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function goToTheBar()
    {
        // DRINK!
    }
}
```

I want a function which will, given the parameter `new Bar()` return:

```
array( 'goToTheBar' );
```

***WITHOUT*** needing to instantiate an instance of Foo.  (This means `get_class_methods` will not work).

Comment: Since your response is not available, I can't verify this, but I believe your statement was something akin to "if you instantiate Bar that will automatically instantiate Foo".  The problem is not my knowledge of scope, the problem is that your post referred to both something on a static level and on the instance.

Comment: My solution was `$class_methods = get_class_methods("Bar");` ... which  does not instantiate anything.

Comment: And I have undeleted my question for you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php), for example:

```
$f = new ReflectionClass('Bar');
$methods = array();
foreach ($f->getMethods() as $m) {
    if ($m->class == 'Bar') {
        $methods[] = $m->name;
    }
}
print_r($methods);
```

Comment: Just to expand on this answer, I needed to read Methods that hadn't been loaded by the Application yet. I was able to run 
include('path/to/class.php'); $f = new ReflectionClass('Class');

This was a great solution. Thanks!

Comment: Slightly more symmetrical: `if ($m->class == $f->name)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `get_class_methods()` without instantiating the class:

> **$class_name** - The class name *or* an
>   object instance.

So the following would work:

```
$bar_methods = array_diff(get_class_methods('Bar'), get_class_methods('Foo'));
```

Assuming there aren't repeated methods in the parent class. Still, [Lukman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010889/list-all-methods-of-a-given-class-excluding-parent-classs-methods-in-php/2010945#2010945) does a better job. =)

Comment: I prefer this answer.  I wanted to get all methods of the current class, excluding parent.  Although this is not what the OP asked for, it might be helpful to someone, somewhere: `array_diff(get_class_methods(__CLASS__),get_class_methods(get_parent_class()))`

Answer (score 2):

```
$class_methods = get_class_methods('Bar');
```

[From the PHP Documenation](http://us.php.net/get_class_methods)

This will not instantiate the class, and will allow you to get an array of all of the classes methods.

I'm not completely certain that this won't return parent class methods, but `get_class_methods` will work for uninstantiated classes. If it does, you can use Alix's answer to remove the parent's method from the array. Or Lukman's to use the reverse engineering aspect of PHP internal code base to get the methods.

---

BTW, if you type in `new Bar()`, it is going to create a new instance of Foo, as Bar extends Foo. The only way you can not instantiate Foo is by referring to it statically. Therefore, your request:

```
I want a function which will, given the parameter new Bar() return:
```

Has no possible solution. If you give `new Bar()` as an argument, it will instantiate the class.

Comment: Aww Man .. Now I feel bad for calling a Senior Software Developer out for not reading the manual.... I'll get over it...

Comment: First, I'd just like to point out that this does not actually answer the question, and it is smarmy.

Comment: Next, I'd like to suggest that it might behoove you to consider the fact there may be good reason I do not wish to instantiate Foo as a separate instance.  An example might be the fact that Foo is a Singleton, which means that you cannot instantiate both Foo and Bar.

Comment: Finally, why the snide remark about reading the manual when your statement, "I'm not completely certain that this won't return parent class methods" is a clear statement that you have made the same error?  Those who dwell in glass houses ought not throw stones...

Comment: I'm not asking you to instantiate bar. If you had take the time in which to read my answer, you would have realized that it does not, in anyway, ask you to instantiate a class.

Comment: And the mention about "I'm not completely certain..." is a clear statement only that I have not had the time to try it out myself. It doesn't mention it in the manual, so therefore I have not made the same error as you.

Comment: And finally, I have removed any sarcastic remarks that you may have been offended by. But, both my and Alix's answer do state that you have made an error thinking that `get_class_methods` cannot handle this task.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering how to check if specific method belongs to specified class or its parent class, you can do this by getting its class name and then comparing it with actual class name like following.

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionMethod($classInstance, 'method_name_here');
if($reflection->class == MyClass::class)
echo "Method belongs to MyClass";
else
echo "Method belongs to Parent classes of MyClass";
```