# How to get model relations in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to get the model relations, in array;

My model look like:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function profile() {
        return $this->haOne(Profile::class);
    }

    public function settings() {
        return $this->morphOne(Settings::class, 'settingsable');
    }

    public function addresses() {
        return $this->hasMany(Addresses::class);
    }
}
```

And my code:

```
$user = User::with(['profile', 'settings', 'addresses'])->find(1);
$user->getRelations(); // return ['profile', 'settings', 'addresses'];
```

If I have more then 10 relation, I don't want to list all.
I would like to get like this:
`$relations = ['profile', 'settings', 'addresses'];`
Is this posible?

Comment: You probably have to load them first: `User::with(['profile', 'settings', 'addresses'])->find(1);`. Not sure what the end goal is here though, relationships aren't included unless you explicitly load them/call them during runtime.

Comment: Yes i found this solution, but that's my original problem, i don't want to list them all.

Comment: If I understand you want a specified list of relations, right?

Comment: I declareted the functions in the model, and i would like to get all of them;

Comment: Possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010889/list-all-methods-of-a-given-class-excluding-parent-classs-methods-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a scope to the model, and so, you have to only write them once.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function profile() {
        return $this->haOne(Profile::class);
    }

    public function settings() {
        return $this->morphOne(Settings::class, 'settingsable');
    }

    public function addresses() {
        return $this->hasMany(Addresses::class);
    }

   public function scopeWithRelations(Builder $query){
      return $query->with([...]);
   }

}

$users = User::withRelations()->get();
```

This way you only have to write them once there, and everywhere in the code you'll use the scope.

Not exactly 100% what you're asking, but this could be a solution.

Comment: I like this solution, but I solved a problem by inserting in to the class a variable: `$relations = [...];`

Comment: Denis's solution is way more elegant than having a variable.